# .NET Core SqlException: Invalid object name 'IdentityUserClaim'. when logging in

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have 2 applications:

ManagementStudio and DocumentStudio. ManagementStudio consists of several dlls that DocumentStudio references.

When I try to login to DocumentStudio, I get this error:

[image]

I'm not sure whats going on because I have included IdentityUserClaim already in the list of my models:

```
[Table("IdentityUserClaim", Schema = "ManagementStudio")]
public class UserClaims : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
    [Key]
    public override int Id { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

```
public DbSet<ApplicationUsers> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserRoles> UserRoles { get; set; }
public DbSet<UserClaims> UserClaims { get; set; }
public DbSet<IdentityUserClaim<string>> IdentityUserClaim { get; set; }
public DbSet<IdentityUserRole<string>> IdentityUserRole { get; set; }
public DbSet<Applications> Applications { get; set; }
public DbSet<Roles> Roles { get; set; }
public DbSet<ApiAccess> ApiAccess { get; set; }
public DbSet<EventLogs> EventLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<ActivityLogs> ActivityLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<CommunicationLogs> CommunicationLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<UploadLogs> UploadLogs { get; set; }
public DbSet<Repositories> Repositories { get; set; }
public DbSet<Emails> Emails { get; set; }
public DbSet<Assets> Assets { get; set; }
public DbSet<Announcements> Announcements { get; set; }
public DbSet<AnnouncementAttachments> AnnouncementAttachments { get; set; }
```

What else can I do to make this work?

EDIT:

I noticed that my CustomClaimsHelper is being called so I'm including it as well:

```
public class CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper<TIdentityUser> where TIdentityUser : IdentityUser
    {

        private readonly SignInManager<TIdentityUser> _signInManager;

        public CustomClaimsCookieSignInHelper(SignInManager<TIdentityUser> signInManager)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        public async Task SignInUserAsync(TIdentityUser user, bool isPersistent, IEnumerable<Claim> customClaims)
        {
            var claimsPrincipal = await _signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            var claims = (from c in claimsPrincipal.Claims select c).ToList();
            var savedClaims = claims;
            if (customClaims != null)
            {
                identity.AddClaims(customClaims);
            }
            await _signInManager.Context.SignInAsync(IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme,
                claimsPrincipal,
                new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = isPersistent });
        }
    }
```

EDIT:

I have tested manually creating a table named IdentityUserClaim with the same columns as my ManagementStudio.IdentityUserClaim table and it works. That means if I remove the Schema for IdentityUserClaim, the app will work. However, is there a way to force DocumentStudio to look for the proper Schema?

Comment: Your connection string is likely pointing to the wrong database.

Comment: My connection string is pointing to the right database. But its asking for the wrong item. Everything in the database has a schema meaning ManagementStudio.IdentityUserClaim But for some reason its not being applied?

Comment: It should be asking for ManagementStudio.IdentityUserClaim but its only asking for IdentityUserClaim